# Reset Listener to parent Activity for recreated Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, listener

I am using a pattern where the activity is a listener to its fragments. The original way I have been creating attaching these fragments is like this:

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment(param1, param2)
myFragment.setListener(this);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, myFragment).commit()
```

But I have learned that this is wrong and that I should be creating the fragment with a static newInstance() method, in case the fragment is destroyed then it can recreate from a bundle. This will let me retain the parameters, but my question is how can I set the listener of a fragment to be its parent activity, after is has been destroyed then recreated?

Is it as simple as calling:

```
setListener((MyActivity) getActivity());
```

within the fragment? This seems wrong to me because it strongly couples the fragment to its parent activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely the wrong route to go. You should have your Activity implement the Fragment's interface (it looks as though you already are, but I'll show an example anyway). Then, within the Fragment, cast the Activity to a listener in `onAttach()` and release it in `onDetach()`. A quick example would be:

### The Fragment

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    private MyFragmentInterface mInterface;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        if (activity instanceof MyFragmentInterface) {
            mInterface = (MyFragmentInterface) activity;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parent Activity must implement MyFragmentInterface.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mInterface = null;
    }

    private void fireOnSomethingHappened () {
        if (mInterface != null) {
            mInterface.onSomethingHappened();
        }
    }

    public static interface MyFragmentInterface {
        void onSomethingHappened();
    }
}
```

### The Activity

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements ExampleFragment.MyFragmentInterface {
    @Override
    public void onSomethingHappened() {
        //Handle the event
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. My only concern was having to cast the activity. Some of my fragments are used in multiple activities so I would just have to check for instanceof each activity.

Comment: But in this way you don't have to do that. You simply cast whatever activity it is to an instance of your *interface*. As long as the Activity implements the interface, it doesn't matter which Activity it is, this code will work.

Comment: Ahhh I misread it. Thanks yes this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: It doesn't work if you HAVE to implement the callback as an anonymous object.

Answer (score 0):

`newInstance()` method should return a fragment instance so you can do something like this:

```
MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(param1, param2)
myFragment.setListener(this);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,    myFragment).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of this, but my question was asking for when the fragment gets destroyed then recreated (not created in the activity code)

Comment: But you dont have to add any extra code on fragment recreation